# Use Hamilton's principle to show expression for $L$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring, variational-principle, coupled-oscillators

I have following diagram

[image]

I have here to find the kinetic energy and the potential energy. I think that kinetic energy is:
$$T=\frac{1}{2} M(\dot{x_1}^2+\dot{x_2}^2)$$
and the potenitial energy must be given as:
$$V(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2} k(x_1^2+x_2^2)+\frac{1}{2}k_{12}(x_2-x_1)^2$$
Is that correct?
Now I have to use Hamilton's principle to show that:
$$L(x_1,x_2,v_1,v_2)=\sum_i \frac{M}{2}|v_i|^2-\frac{k}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2)-\frac{k_{12}}{2}(x_1-x_2)^2$$
I'm not sure how to do that. I can't find something about it in my lecture notes so I think it's something we have to learn by the exercises here. I have found that $L=T-V$ is the lagragian, and some big integral is equal to $0$, and I think maybe I have to use this? But I can't see how the $v_1$ and $v_2$ comes in the expression for $L$? while we have none $v_1$ and $v_2$ in the expressions for $T$ and $V$?. I have not a physiscal background but a mathematical background, but I think I have understand the diagram and found the right terms for the kinetic energy and the potential energy. Or is it totally wrong? But can anyone help me using the Hamilton's principle to show that expression for $L$? Hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 1):

Hamilton's principle is used to derive the Euler-Lagrange equation, the equation of motion of the system.

I think what you have to show in this problem is $H=T+V$ using the definition of the Hamiltonian. Once you calculate the Lagrangian $L=T-V$, you can then calculate \begin{equation}H=\sum_i p_i q_i-L=x_1v_1+x_2v_2-L\end{equation} in order to prove that $H=T+V$.